# How to calculate total average of multiple variables by category

Tags: spss

V1 = Place where you buy ITEM1 (Ordinal)

C1 = Cost of ITEM1 (Scale)

V2 = Place where you buy ITEM2 (Ordinal)

C2 = Cost of ITEM2 (Scale)

I need to calculate the total average spend by place.

Regards;

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a bit of restructure and then aggregating.

first - creating some fake data to play with:

```
data list list/v1 (a10) c1 (f4) v2 (a10) c2 (f4).
begin data
aaa 10 bbb 20
ccc 30 bbb 40
ccc 60 aaa 40
bbb 90 bbb 10
end data.
dataset name OrigData.
```

now, restructuring will change the data so there's only one variable for places, with the relevant cost attached:

```
varstocases /make Place from V1 V2/make Cost from C1 C2.
```

now this is easily aggregated by place:

```
DATASET DECLARE CostByPlace.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='CostByPlace' /BREAK=Place 
     /Cost_sum=SUM(Cost) /Cost_mean_1=MEAN(Cost).
```